# Label jigging during animation

Tags: jsxgraph

Hi everyone
Here is a little problem I encountered: Labels are jiggling during animation, as shown in the codepen.

```
let board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {axis: false,});
let dummy = {t:0};
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  board.create('point', [()=> -4 + dummy.t, ()=> 4 -dummy.t - i], {
    showInfobox:false,
    label: {
      anchorX: 'left', 
      anchorY: 'top',
      fontSize: 30,
    },
  });
}
gsap.to(dummy, {
  ease: 'power2.inOut',
  duration:10,
  t:3,
  onUpdate: ()=> board.update()
})
```

https://codepen.io/ywlee/pen/yLbgxpV

The only way I can think of is to shorten the animation time

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you for reading my problem:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My impression is that the jiggling is slightly reduced if SVG texts are used for the point labels (i.e. internal texts):

```
board.create('point', [()=> -4 + dummy.t, ()=> 4 -dummy.t - i], {
    showInfobox:false,
    label: {
        display: 'internal', // <-- SVG texts instead of HTML texts
        anchorX: 'left', 
        anchorY: 'top',
        fontSize: 30,
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I don't know if this is true, is that because in the source code, position of the label is rounded before render? 
I'm not sure about it because I don't know if I trace all the function calls correctly

Comment: Could you please tell me how to fix it? because I think I will use a lots of katex in labels, which can not be 'internal' @Alfred

Comment: Yes, the position of the labels is rounded to integer values of pixels. I can try to experiment if non-integer values will help in your case.
However, more probably the cause for the jiggling is a rerendering of the katex texts during updates. Can you please check, if this is the case? One workaround could be to use a custom CSS class for labels with fixed width and height. Then at least the JSXGraph part of the rendering should be smooth.

Comment: I've edited the same codepen in the question as a new example.
A label with the same string rendered by Katex looks pretty same to the html one.
I also tried to remove `Math.round` in the `updateText` function, now katex labels are as smooth as internal ones!
I'm really really appreciate your quick and patient replies, they are extremely helpful to me, I hope I can learn coding faster and can contribute to this project as soon as possible @Alfred

Comment: Thanks a lot for your research work. Rounding is now disabled in the sources for v1.2.4 (branch 1.2.4 on github).